# Search the Entire DB2 DB

Tags: db2

I have a specific value, let's say 'resource 1'. I need to find all instances of this in the database as I need to do an update on the format to change it to Resource 2.

How can I do this? The database is in IBM DB2 10.5.

Comment: When you say "update on the format" are you simply saying you need to update all occurrences of the value "Resource 1" to the new value "Resource 2"?  Or do you need to do something more complicated?

Comment: I need to update all the occurrences of the value "resource 1" to "Resource 2"

Answer (score 1):

Well, that could be done with a stored procedure or app in a brute force-like manner:

1. Query S**YSCAT.COLUMNS** for all columns, maybe limited to string types
2. Within that, query each column with **LIKE** or equality for "resource 1". This could already be done as searched **UPDATE**.

Performance? Why? Doesn't look like a good idea.